# Shell Exec não roda abrindo pelo navegador

Tags: php, servidor

Fiz uma lista de comandos para ser executados no servidor usando php, que ficou da seguinte forma

```
echo shell_exec("sudo mkdir teste");
echo shell_exec("sudo chown apache:ind teste/");
echo shell_exec("sudo unzip image.zip -d teste/");
```

Executando direto no servidor com o comando

```
sudo php -f teste.php
```

Tudo que esta dentro do documento é executado, porém se eu tentar executar pelo navegador, por exemplo

```
www.minhaurl.com/teste.php
```

Comment: Vai no `php.ini` e procura a linha `disable_functions`, tire da lista o `shell_exec`.

Comment: Não Rolou, continua não executando :/

Comment: Achei isso aqui https://stackoverflow.com/a/38523143/11379709 diz que deve-se adicionar uma regra para que o sudo rode não peça o password para a página.

Comment: Acho que não deu certo também :/ que chato isso

Comment: Como você está reiniciando o servidor, após  as alterações?

Comment: sudo service named restart, deu certo a atualização, pois nao consigo mais executar pelo pronpt, mas mesmo assim, não funciona pelo navegador :(